# How to convert this t-sql script?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I am unfamiliar with Oracle and i need to have equivalent of my script for Oracle.

Script:

```
SELECT  COL_NAME(parent_object_id, parent_column_id) AS ForigneKeyField,
        COL_NAME(referenced_object_id, referenced_column_id) AS PrimaryKeyField,
        OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_id) AS PrimaryTable
FROM    sys.foreign_key_columns
WHERE   parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(@name)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm unfamiliar with t-sql but I am familiar with Oracle, so:

It appears you are querying the data dictionary for all referential integrity constraints for a given table, and for each, reporting the foreign key field(s), and the relevant field and table for the table they refer to.

In Oracle this information is kept in the `ALL_CONSTRAINTS` and `ALL_CONS_COLUMNS` data dictionary views (or `DBA_CONSTRAINTS / DBA_CONS_COLUMNS or USER_CONSTRAINTS / USER_CONS_COLUMNS`, depending on what the scope of your query should be). I would run a query like this:

```
SELECT fc.constraint_name   AS ForeignConstraint
      ,fc.r_constraint_name AS ReferencedConstraint
      ,fcc.column_name      AS ForeignKeyField
      ,rcc.column_name      AS ReferencedKeyField
      ,rc.table_name        AS ReferencedTable
FROM   sys.all_constraints  fc
      ,sys.all_constraints  rc
      ,sys.all_cons_columns fcc
      ,sys.all_cons_columns rcc
WHERE  fc.table_name        = :name
AND    fc.constraint_type   = 'R'
AND    fc.r_constraint_name = rc.constraint_name
AND    fc.constraint_name   = fcc.constraint_name
AND    rc.constraint_name   = rcc.constraint_name
AND    fcc.position         = rcc.position
ORDER BY fc.constraint_name, fcc.position;
```

I've added the constraint names in the query (ForeignConstraint and ReferencedConstraint) which are useful when referential constraints involve concatenated keys.